# Current Divider Formula Proof

Tags: current, current-measurement

Just recently, I was watching a video where the presenter used a current divider formula (I think he called it the "G" rule) to calculate the current flowing throw a resistor on a circuit with two resistors in parallel.

Basically, given two resistor in parallel as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSQxOK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current divider formula he was using to calculate the current flowing through R2 was something like this:

I2 = ( (1/R2)/(1/R2 + 1/R1) ) * ITotal

In case it helps, the link to the part of the video were he uses the rule is here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF2XmaG2-Cw#t=411

I am pretty new to all these so I was hoping that someone could tell me how this current divider formula is derived (proof of the formula)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's define \$G_1=1/R_1\$ and \$G_2=1/R_2\$. These values are *conductances*, the dual of resistances.

Now we can restate Ohm's law in terms of conductance: \$I=VG\$.

Then, the current through conductor #2, \$I_2\$, is \$VG_2\$, and or our two conductors in parallel, the current \$I\$ is \$V\left(G_1+G_2\right)\$.

Now to get \$I_2 / I\$ we just divide:

$$\frac{I_2}{I}=\frac{VG_2}{V(G_1+G_2)}$$

Cancel the *V*'s and convert the *G*'s back to *R*'s and you have your "G rule".

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should try Ohm's law, the good old U=R.I :

\$U=R1\cdot I1=R2\cdot I2\$

\$I=I1+I2 = U\cdot (\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}) \rightarrow U=\frac{I}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}\$

\$I2=\frac{U}{R2} = \frac{1}{R2} \cdot U = I \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{R2}}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}\$

Etc...

Comment: [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt): "The volt (symbol: V) is the derived unit for electric potential, electric potential difference (voltage), and electromotive force.[1] The volt is named in honour of the Italian physicist Alessandro Volta (1745–1827), who invented the voltaic pile, possibly the first chemical battery." \$ \ \$  Electromotive force is assigned the symbol \$\xi\$, which is often transliterated as "E", for convenience, but _NOWHERE_ is "U" used - properly - as the symbol for voltage.

Comment: Ha, caught ! This is a local habit. Compare ohm's law description in the English, Italian, Spanish Wikipedia with the French or German versions. There is no reason to write electrical potentials as V : Currents are not written with A, resistances are not written with a capital omega, time with a s... Units symbols seldom match variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Total current = current through R1 + Current through R2

*ie*, \$I_{tot} = \frac{V}{R_1} + \frac{V}{R_2}\$

*or*, \$V = I_{tot}/(1/R_1 + 1/R_2)\$

Then current through R2 is
\$I_2 = \frac{V}{R_2}=I_{tot}\times \frac{1/R_2}{1/R_1+1/R_2}\$

Answer (score 0):

V=I1*R1=I2*R2
ITotal=I1+I2
Itotal=V/R1+V/R2=V(1/R1+1/R2)
V=Itotal/(1/R1+1/R2)
I2=v/R2= 1/R2*ITotal/(1/R1+1/R2)
After simplification by taking LCM in the denominator and cancelling the term 'R2' we get,
I2=ITotal*R1/(R1+R2)

similarly, the current through the Resistor 'R1' is given by,

I1=ITotal*R2/(R1+R2)